# Getting Early Timed Out After Calling ASP.NET Webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis-7

I have a asp.net web-service hosted under (IIS7 ,windows server 2008) and i am doing some timed out test. every time its getting timed out after **2 minute** from the request. and says:

> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after
>   **00:04:59.5539745**. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to
>   Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time
>   allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer
>   timeout.

But things getting interesting when i have hosted this service under (IIS7,windows 7 64 bit) and also in another (IIS7, Windows Server 2008) and its not getting timed out after 2 minute (Timed out as configured (5 minute) in client side)

configurations (client side) are,

```
<binding name="TestWebserviceSoap" closeTimeout="00:05:00"
          openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
```

> **What i am doing wrong or what might be the wrong with the first windows server 2008?**

I see the [.NET Web Service (asmx) Timeout Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064416/net-web-service-asmx-timeout-problem)

But does not got the answer from there.

**Edit:**

The service is hosted in a different network from mine and i am accessing this service through a real IP that is pointing to the Local machine where the service is hosted.

The Actual exception Is:

> System.TimeoutException: The remote server returned an error: (504)
>   Gateway Timeout. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server
>   returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout.

Comment: Did you verify your httpruntime timeout on the server that is causing issues?

Comment: I did see the runtime timed out configuration on the IIS where it is hosted. everything is seems fine. i also did see the machine configuration and it seems also fine. but the service is hosted in a different network from mine and i am accessing this service through a real IP that is pointing to the Local machine where the service is hosted. @Brian